# Dequeue complexity on using Python list as a queue

Tags: python, time-complexity

A list is used as a queue such that the first element is the head of the queue. I was discussing the complexity of dequeue operation in such data structure with my teacher, who said it is O(1). My thinking is, if you're removing the first element of the list, wouldn't that be O(n), since then all elements after that first element need to be shifted over a spot? Am I looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: Your answer can be found here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity It seems you are right and your teacher is wrong unless your teacher meant the end of a list.

Comment: It's `O(n)` if you are storing the elements in a `list` but `O(1)` if you're using a data structure to link to nodes of the queue.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct. List in Python is inefficient at dequeuing since all items following the item being dequeued need to be copied to their preceding positions like you say. You can instead use `collections.deque`, which is implemented with a doubly-linked list, so that you can use the `popLeft` method to dequeue efficiently in *O(1)* time complexity.

Comment: Yup, my teacher just made a test-correction to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you find it to be correct? (Click on the grey check mark next to the answer.)

Answer (score -1):

Your teacher probably thought python `list` is a linked list. It is not. From [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-queues):

> It is also possible to use a list as a queue, where the first element added is the first element retrieved (“first-in, first-out”); however, lists are not efficient for this purpose. While appends and pops from the end of list are fast, doing inserts or pops from the beginning of a list is slow (because all of the other elements have to be shifted by one).

Indeed, the doc suggested you to use `collections.deque` for this purpose.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct. Python's list is an array-list, so, not appropriate for popping from head. Instead, use `collections.deque` for O(1) add/remove at first element.